# Ribbon with round edge

Tags: css

I try to make this code:

https://codepen.io/HenryGuillen17/pen/baGxYj

```
<div class="ribbon"></div>
```

but it does not really come out. I want to make a ribbon which has those continuous edges, but I have not succeeded. In my work they demand that I then make an animation, as if I were taking off a curtain, but that could do it, we'll see.

The truth is that I must make that ribbon for a web page and I could not find the solution.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think this will be possible without using SVG. Using SVG would help assist you in your future efforts to animate like a curtain.

Comment: Mmmm, I do not use svg, but at least I should see how I do that in some way, or something like that.

Comment: It's possible I'm trying a solution right now

Comment: @HenryGuillen17 I made a quick SVG version for you: https://codepen.io/ahdigital/pen/xpxQrm

Comment: I added two final parts to the end of the ribbon because when skewing an element  it will be easy to adjust the pseudo elements for it. Check this out: https://codepen.io/Marouen/pen/KZKrYR?editors=1100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added two final parts to the end of the ribbon because when skewing an element it will be easy to adjust the pseudo elements for it

HTML:

```
<div class="ribbon">
</div>
<div class="final-ribbon-part1">
<div class="final-ribbon-part2">
```

(S)CSS:

```
body {
  margin : 0 !important;
}

$left-window: 10px;
$width-ribbon : 150px;
$height-ribbon : 300px;
$top-ribbon: 0px;
$left-ribbon: 0px;
$grosor-borde: 2px;
.ribbon {
  top: $top-ribbon;
  left: $left-ribbon;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: $left-window;
  background-color: #DDD;
  width: $width-ribbon;
  height: $height-ribbon;
  border-radius : 0 0 35px 35px;
  z-index: 1;
  //border: 1px solid black;

  background: rgba(147,186,19,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(147,186,19,1) 0%, rgba(147,186,19,1) 50%, rgba(2,102,45,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(147,186,19,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(147,186,19,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(2,102,45,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(147,186,19,1) 0%, rgba(147,186,19,1) 50%, rgba(2,102,45,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(147,186,19,1) 0%, rgba(147,186,19,1) 50%, rgba(2,102,45,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(147,186,19,1) 0%, rgba(147,186,19,1) 50%, rgba(2,102,45,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(147,186,19,1) 0%, rgba(147,186,19,1) 50%, rgba(2,102,45,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#93ba13', endColorstr='#02662d', GradientType=0 );

   &:before {
    height: $height-ribbon - 20;
    border-left: $grosor-borde dashed #da5050;
    border-right: $grosor-borde dashed #da5050;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: $width-ribbon * 0.9;
    left : $left-ribbon + 6px;
  }
  &:after {
    height: $height-ribbon - 10;
    border-left: $grosor-borde dashed #631a15;
      border-right: $grosor-borde dashed #631a15;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: ($width-ribbon * 0.9) - 10;
    left : $left-ribbon + 6px + 5;
  } 
}
.final-ribbon-part1 {
  top: $top-ribbon + $height-ribbon - 40px;
  left: 11px;
  background-color: #03662c;
  width: 74px;
  height: 147px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 90%;
  z-index: -1;
  &:before {
    height: 96%;
    width: 92%;
    border-bottom: $grosor-borde dashed #da5050;
    border-left: $grosor-borde dashed #da5050;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 90%;
    top: 0;
    left: 3.5px;
  } 
  &:after {
    top: 0;
    height: 92%;
    width: 92%;
    border-left: $grosor-borde dashed #631a15;
      border-bottom: $grosor-borde dashed #631a15;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left : 10px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 90%;
  }
}

.final-ribbon-part2 {
  top: 0px;
  left: 74px;
  background-color: #03662c;
  width: 74px;
  height: 147px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0 90%;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  &:before {
    height: 96%;
    width: 92%;
    border-bottom: $grosor-borde dashed #da5050;
    border-left: $grosor-borde dashed #da5050;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 90%;
    top: 0;
    left: 3.5px;
  } 
  &:after {
    top: 0;
    height: 92%;
    width: 86%;
    border-left: $grosor-borde dashed #631a15;
      border-bottom: $grosor-borde dashed #631a15;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left : $left-ribbon + 6px  + 2;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 98%;
  } 
}
```

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/Marouen/pen/KZKrYR?editors=1100

Comment: That's very good, I would never have imagined using two parts for the end. This is how it works for my website. Thank you very much

Comment: no problem :-)! You may have to play around with the widths and heights to make it look perfekt!